# Hide Object outside of viewportTransform visualization

Tags: fabricjs

I'm trying to make my app more performant. In order to do this I think I could hide, with `visibility: false` some Objects that are not in the current viewportTransform visualization and show them just when the viewportTransform is on its boundaries.

Is there any method to know if an object is inside of this "view"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fabric.js already [does that](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/blob/master/src/shapes/object.class.js#L1039) for you.

This check is controlled by [Canvas.skipOffscreen](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#skipOffscreen) (defaults to `true`).